# PowerShell FSW script not functioning

Tags: .net, powershell

I am attempting to monitor a folder that users will be copying folders with files into a common space.  Once the folder is copied the script is supposed to create a target folder and for each file in the source folder execute a batch file with two variables passed; the first is the file name the second is the target folder.  Once all of the files are processed the script should move the source folder to an archive and rename it with the '_Archive' text added to the name.

I cannot get any part of the script to execute correctly.  When I check job status it shows as failed.  If I stop the job and remove it I cannot unregister the event.  Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the script:

```
$inputFolder = 'c:\cat2proe\convertSource'      # Enter the root path of the   source folder.
$filter = '*.*'                                 # You can enter a wildcard filter here.
$outputFolder = 'c:\cat2proe\convertDest'       # Enter the root path of the destination folder
$storageFolder = 'c:\cat2proe\Archive'          # Enter the root path of the archive folder

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $inputFolder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $true;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'DirectoryName'}

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FolderCreated -Action {
$convFolder = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
$fpath = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
$workFolder= $inputFolder + "\" + $convFolder
$targetFolder = $outputFolder + "\" + $convFolder + "_converted"
$archiveFolder = $storageFolder + "\" + $convFolder + "_archived"
$files = Get-ChildItem $workFolder
New-Item -Path $targetFolder -ItemType directory -Force
New-Item -Path $targetFolder + "\log" -ItemType directory -Force
ForEach ($file in $files) { 
catia5batch.bat $file.fullName $targetFolder | Out-File -FilePath $targetFolder + "\log\conversionLog.log" -Append -InputObject log "$($_.BaseName)$(get-date -Format MM-dd-yyyy)$($_.extension) has been converted successfully."}
Move-Item -path $workFolder -destination $archiveFolder -Force
}
```

Comment: "job status"? - I don't see any jobs being created. Please post the relevant source code along with error messages. Also it is helpful to potential answers if you indent your source . BTW It looks like you have unmatched braces in the code you posted. There is an open brace for `Register-ObjectEvent` and for `ForEach` but only 1 close brace. And your code for `Register-ObjectEvent` uses the variable `$Event`, but it isn't defined. You likely missed the `Param()` statement. I suggest you go back and review the description of the code in the place where you obtained the code.

Comment: @user2460798 `$Event` is an automatic variable in that context, doesn't need declaration

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks. Is that true in PS 2.0?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen then that's probably a good reason to tell a questioner that $Event is undefined.

Comment: @user2460798 It is true in PS 2.0, yes

Comment: I apologize for any formatting or incomplete pieces of information.       @User2460798 - The second close bracket for the ForEach is located at the end of the line with the log output **_converted successfully."}_** the last close bracket is for the Object event.  I have reviewed the source code I based the script off of which is located at [Powershell FileSystemWatcher](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b) and there is no declaration of the $Event parameter there.  I will post the exact error messages later today.  Thank you.